# NSString Detect Number then Parenthesis

Tags: ios, ipad, nsstring, formatting, calculator

I am making an iOS calculator app. I would like to be able to find occurrences of a number character and a parenthesis right next to each other in a string, like these examples:

- **23(8+9)**
- **(89+2)(78)**
- **(7+8)9**

I would like to be able to insert a character between these occurances:

- *23(8+9) would be* **23*(8+9)**
- *(89+2)(78) would be* **(89+2)*(78)**
- *(7+8)9 would be* **(7+8)*9**

Comment: Doesn't your first example change the meaning of the expression?

Comment: Seems like a suitable task for DDMathParser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick function I cooked up which uses regular expressions to find your matching pattern and then inserts a "*" where needed.  It matches either two parentheses ")(" or a number and parenthesis "5(" or ")3" for example.  It will also work if there's space in between for example ")  5".

Feel free to adjust the function to fit your needs.  Not sure if this is the best way to do it, but it works.

For more information about regular expressions see the [documentation for NSRegularExpression](http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

```
- (NSString *)stringByInsertingMultiplicationSymbolInString:(NSString *)equation {
    // Create a mutable copy so we can manipulate it
    NSMutableString *mutableEquation = [equation mutableCopy];

    // The regexp pattern matches:
    // ")(" or "n(" or ")n"  (where n is a number).
    // It also matches if there's whitepace in between (eg. (4+5)  (2+3) will work)
    NSString *pattern = @"(\\)\\s*?\\()|(\\d\\s*?\\()|(\\)\\s*?\\d)";

    NSError *error;
    NSRegularExpression *regexp = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
    NSArray *matches = [regexp matchesInString:equation options:NSMatchingReportProgress range:NSMakeRange(0, [equation length])];

    // Keep a counter so that we can offset the index as we go
    NSUInteger count = 0;
    for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches) {
        [mutableEquation insertString:@"*" atIndex:match.range.location+1+count];
        count++;
    }

    return mutableEquation;
}
```

This is how I tested it:

```
NSString *result;

result = [self stringByInsertingMultiplicationSymbolInString:@"23(8+9)"];
NSLog(@"Result: %@", result);

result = [self stringByInsertingMultiplicationSymbolInString:@"(89+2)(78)"];
NSLog(@"Result: %@", result);

result = [self stringByInsertingMultiplicationSymbolInString:@"(7+8)9"];
NSLog(@"Result: %@", result);
```

This will output:

```
Result: 23*(8+9)
Result: (89+2)*(78)
Result: (7+8)*9
```

Note: This code uses ARC, so remember to autorelease the copied string if you're using MRC.

Comment: Wow! Amazing! I'm going with DDMathParser, but you get marked correct!